# Webpack 5 is failing to compile Microsoft Word add-in using React JS when I add import for CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, word-addins

I see I am not the first to have this issue, but I've tried all the answers given previously and the error refuses to go away. I've tried with and without CSS modules.
The error is:
ERROR in ./src/taskpane/components/ui/Card.module.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

The Card.js file is simple:

```
// import './Card.css';
import css from './Card.module.css';

function Card() {
    return <div className={css.card}></div>
}

export default Card;
```

The Card.module.css only has a couple of CSS rules:

```
.card {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

package.json has these versions in devDependencies:

```
"css-loader": "^6.7.1",
"style-loader": "^3.3.1",
"webpack": "^5.50.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "4.7.4"
```

I've got this in webpack.config.js:

```
resolve: {
      extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".html", ".js", ".css"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                importLoaders: 1,
                modules: true
              }
            }
          ]
        },
```

Is there anything else that needs to be shown to solve this? I didn't want to create a TL;DR question by adding every line of code.
I've been banging my head against this for hours, trying all the suggestions I could find, but none have worked.
TIA